# Drag and drop re-order tasks under stories in TFS2013

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to order tasks under stories in the TFS2013 web interface, by dragging them with the mouse? And additionally is it possible to drag them into new stories?

Currently I have to open up the task and manually set the `Stack Rank` to re-arrange items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot reorder tasks in the web site no.  You can move them to a new story by drag and drop but only on the board not the backlog.